# Cloning environment with selected packages in conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I would like to know if it is possible to clone an environment with the selected packages only.

Doing `conda create -n name --clone base` will clone the `base` environment including all the packages which sometimes unnecessary for a certain project.

Uninstalling the packages on the new environment could be a solution but I'm   trying to find a way that is more effective and explicit.

Comment: No. Clone means clone - copy entirely. If you only want certain packages, export an `environment.yml` file and edit it to remove packages you don't want, then use that to create a new environment.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on what @darthbith said.  Cloning creates an exact copy of every package in the environment.  If you want to clone only a portion of the environment, you can create a spec file using:

```
conda list -n base --export > environment.yaml
```

This will dump a list of every package in the base environment as a yaml file.  You can edit the file to keep only the packages you want and conda will figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

This command spawns another conda environment `test1` with the requested packages `numpy scipy pandas` from the base one without downloading anything:

```
conda create -n test1 --offline numpy scipy pandas
```